# How do i differentiate unit tests from integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I have all dependencies mocked, stubbed for the test below.
Is this still considered a unit test or an integration test?
I have read in an article online that you should separate the two, unit tests should be ran as often as possible, and integration tests once in a while.
I don't have a lot of experience with unit testing, and I am having difficulties distinguishing between the two.

For example I have added new functionality and the test below fails, but I have tested the application code and it works as intended. I feel that my tests are too brittle, and I currently need to keep changing the test or adding to it when i am changing my source code, that doesn't seem right to me.

```
TEST_F(UserInterfaceTest, TransmitCalibrationWithWrongPacket)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> commandpathnames;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            std::string txt("transmit_calibration");
            txt += std::to_string(i);
            txt += ".txt";

            commandpathnames.push_back(txt);
        }

        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, DisableAndSwitchPanel());
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, CheckInstance(_, _));
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetSerialPortInstance()).WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(serialport));
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetSerialPortAddress()).WillOnce(Return(port));
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetCalibration()).WillRepeatedly(Return(calib));

        EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, SetFunction(_));
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetFunction()).WillOnce(Return(TRANSMIT_CALIBRATION));
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetTemperature());
        EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetSurveyDelay()).WillOnce(Return(20));

        EXPECT_CALL(*calib, GetCommandPathNames()).WillRepeatedly(Return(commandpathnames));

        EXPECT_CALL(serialport, Read(_))
            .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(poll), Return(0)));

        EXPECT_CALL(serialport, Write(_))
            .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(identitycommand), Return(0)));

        EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, CustomEventDisplayData(_)).Times(AtLeast(1));

        EXPECT_EQ(wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR, m_Controller->TransmitMasCalibration());

        m_Controller->GetSemaphore()->Wait();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), you find for *unit testing*:

> unit testing is a software testing method by which individual units of source code, sets of one or more computer program modules together with associated control data, usage procedures, and operating procedures, are tested to determine whether they are fit for use.

In other words: **any** kind of test you do can be called a **unit** test.

Thing is: that definition isn't helpful. Sites like [art of unit testing](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) are more specific:

> Runs in memory (no DB or File access, for example)

Leading to: "true" unit tests run in complete isolation. You cut of *any* ties to its dependencies (unless these dependencies execute "fine" within your unit test environment).

Coming from that perspective: as long as your unit tests do not require your complete stack to be up and running, or that something is reachable on some network interface ... they are probably unit tests.

I rather differentiate between unit tests and *functional* tests. They both exercise a small piece, but the later one with one or more dependencies that are "really" there.

Integration tests go even one step further - here you have almost no "stubbing" of dependencies.

But the real answer is: these terms are **fuzzy**. Different people have different views. And it is almost impossible to change their views. Therefore the real conclusion is: *you* (and your team) should clearly define what these terms mean to you, and then you make sure that everybody working on that code based at least knows about that vision.

Regarding the "too brittle" aspect: there are again two views here. On the one hand, you focus on testing **public contracts**. Ideally, you can completely replace one implementation with another one, and your unit tests still work. Because ideally, your unit tests do "given this input, expect that output (behavior)" only. As soon as you start testing implementation details, your tests break when implementation changes. Which makes the tests less valuable.

On the other hand, it might also be fair to test for specific "internal" elements. Then well, you need to test them.

But as said: the *first* approach is about testing the public contract, the "what", not the "how".

Comment: Thanks! From your answer it looks like the example code above is a unit test. I will need to rethink how Internal states are tested. Do you recommend to have a separate project for integration tests?

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez That is more of a "style" question. I think you should research whether there is a "standard" that is common in your specific "industry", otherwise: talk to your peers. There are no rules carved in stone here, so basically *you* are free to decide which rules make sense to you and you intend  to follow. For me personally, I always vote for "segregation of concerns", so having a distinct "bucket" or "project" for specific types of test sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: luckily i am free to decide whatever, but it is also difficult because there are only two of us in our team, and we pretty much work independently.